# UITextField catching textFieldDidBeginEditing event causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

This is mystifying.

My view controller implements the UITextFieldDelegate protocol in the .h file, and in the .mm file, I have

```
myTextField.delegate = self
```

And my textFieldDidBeginEditing event is simply a NSLog message.

When I run my program and set focus on myTextField, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

It must be an obvious blunder I have somewhere, but it's been troubling me all night. Anybody knows why? And how I can catch the begin-edit event of a textField?

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing that NSLog statement and see if it gets there?  Also, are you using XCode 4?

Comment: yes I am using xcode 4, and the break point does not hit. Further tests confirms that it sometimes doesn't raise the error, but the break point never hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foremost, Xcode 4 changed the behavior of the debugger.  On the debugger panel on the left, there should be a slider all the way at the bottom - showing you MORE or LESS stack frames.  You're showing the top stack frame (UIApplication) -- chances are if you slide that slider you'll see more of an idea of where you are crashing.

Also, if it's EXC_BAD_ACCESS, have you turned on NSZombieEnabled = YES as an environment variable to catch what is being over-released?  Usually it's a memory problem.

Comment: Bingo, it was an over-release issue. The detailed stack is useful too. Learned several things in one single post. Thank you very much.